# Multiple physicians -( i.e. primary , secondary , referring ) . Where to keep them in fhir

Tags: hl7, hl7-fhir

I am looking for the right place to keep multiple physicians.

So far the choices are :

1. DiagnosticOrder.orderer = Physicians
2. Patient.CareProvider = Physicians
3. Encounter.Participant = Physicians

Can you please suggest the right place to keep different physicians?

Answer (score 1):

For DSTU2, care teams are handled using CarePlan.